# Missing explicit cast in MVC Repository class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oop, model-view-controller

What I am going to ask is something really easy. But I just don't seem to make it work. I am developing an MVC app with EF with the repository pattern.

Following code is method in the Repository class.
When ever I try to retrive from Dbset,  I get this error - missing explicit cast for IQueryable to IQueryable
or
missing explicit cast for Generic.List to Generic.List
or
missing explicit cast for contextclass> to model class when I retrive a single

```
public List<ProdModal> getProducts ()
   {
       List<ProdModal> grp = new List<ProdModal>();
       var prod = (from r in context.ProdContext
                     select r).ToList();
       return prod;
   }



public void get1Products()
  {
      using (var context = new Entities())
      {
          IList<ProdModal> rtn = from temp in context.ProdContext select  temp;
          var list = rtn.ToList();
      }

  }
```

[rectified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHWyd.png)

In all the posts, I see that this is a workable code. Is my intent wrong or am I missing a step here. Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.

Update
I added a parameterized constructer and changed the code to include

```
public List<RTS_Active> GetRTSActiveByID(string typeID)
   {
       var machine = (from r in context.RTS_ACTIVE
                      where (r.TYPEID == typeID)
                      select  new RTSOp.Models.RTS_Active ());
       return machine.ToList();
   }
```

now the fetch works properly. Now my other problem is my Add is showing error such as below:
[need help for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Emk4.png)

Comment: Please do not paraphrase; post the actual error message (cut and paste works great). Also, kindly indicate the line of code that causes the error.

Comment: `from temp in context.ProdContext select  temp` => this LINQ query expression returns `IQueryable<ProdModal>`, but you're assign it to `IList<ProdModal>`. You need to use `ToList()` to assign into `IList` or `IQueryable<ProdModal>` type.

Comment: @ Tetsuya Yamamoto - I tried your suggestion. Pls refer pic. Still shows error. In whatever way the data is fetched, the error persists. Am I missing any step that I should have already done?

Comment: I see that the returned object namespace has `EDMX` name on them, while in return type doesn't use `EDMX` name in namespace. You need to use `select new RTSOp.Models.[[DTOModelNameHere]]` and assign all properties from query source to the DTO class.

Comment: thanks @TetsuyaYamamoto , the retreival works. But I still need help with Add(). Would you recommend adding constructors to the context class? pls advise